# Starting a virtual machine in virtual box or vmware player freezes linux host

Tags: linux, virtualization

I'm running Kubuntu 10.04 with kernel version 2.6

i.e. output from uname -a

```
Linux blaze 2.6.32-24-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 19 01:38:40 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I created the virtual machine without any dramas, but the problem is that when I start the virtual machine the Kubuntu host OS freezes completely.  Mouse stops responding, not responsive to any user input, just hung.

Is this a known issue, is there a workaround?   Apparently disabling VTx is a solution for some, but I absolutely need to install windows 7 64bit.  32bit version is not an option for me.

Interestingly, thought I'd try using VM Player Application and the same thing happened.

I have a Q8400 CPU and VT extensions are enabled in the bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.

I actually now have it working.  I read somewhere that someone else was having this exact same issue.  Once they updated their BIOS it worked.  I did the same and lo and behold, it works.

One thing though is that you have to disable USB support.  There is some sort of bug in virtual box that also causes the host to lock up.

See: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=20015